# Single Multi-Tenancy DB with 100K concurrent users

Tags: sql-server, performance, multi-tenant

I have a DB that is currently not normalized and will be getting about 100K concurrent users that will mostly be doing Read-Only operations from multiple tables. 
I am trying to figure out if I should start thinking of having a DB per client (1000 clients) or if I should normalize the database and keep it as a single DB with good indexes and partitioning.

I am looking for any ideas that you may have.

Hardware is not a problem but 100K concurrent users is.

Thoughts?

Comment: This would be better on http://dba.stackexchange.com I think.  FYI SQL has a limit of 32767 concurrent users -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.120).aspx so you're going to need multiple servers anyway.  But normalization is always suggested for performance.

Comment: @JiggsJedi: That is not a limitation of SQL, surely, just a limitation of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes specifically SQL Server... you're right other RDBMS may very well handle more.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Or less. I'd love to see what MySQL does under the load of 30K users, never mind 100K.

Comment: Thanks for the info, may have to look into other options besides MSSQL server...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - just for giggles... MySQL boasts a mind boggling 4,294,967,295 connection limit.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections -- how's that for false advertising :)

Comment: I was just looking at that page and scratching my head. Wonder how the perf is on MySQL at 100K connections.... Hmmmm

Comment: Good luck. I know what's like on basic WordPress installs with 10 concurrent users.